# Is the Nisnevich topology quasi compact?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

We only consider schemes that are smooth and separated over a field $K$. Let $\{X_i\longrightarrow X\}_{i\in I}$ be a Nisnevich covering of a scheme $X$ (all $X_i$ and $X$ are smooth and separated). Then, I believe there is a finite subcover (?)

Could anyone please give me a precise reference for this? Further, is it necessary to assume that the schemes here are smooth and separated?

Comment: Let $X$ be an infinite disjoint union of copies of the spectrum of $K$.  This is smooth and separated over $K$.  If we let $X_i$ be the connected components, we get a counterexample.

Comment: As the above comment shows, it's not even true for the Zariski topology, which is much coarser. But perhaps you meant for $X$ to be finite type over $K$ (not just locally of finite type over $K$), and then noetherian induction provides the finite subcover (using openness of etale morphisms).